# Counting times column values change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```py
df = DataFrame({'date': {379724: '2017-01-31',
  379725: '2017-01-31',
  414510: '2017-02-14',
  414509: '2017-02-28',
  414511: '2017-02-28',
  507215: '2017-04-27',
  507213: '2017-04-27',
  507214: '2017-04-27',
  507235: '2017-04-27',
  562139: '2017-04-27',
  672967: '2017-07-27',
  672968: '2017-07-27',
  672969: '2017-07-27',
  910729: '2017-12-07',
  990263: '2018-01-30',
  990265: '2018-01-30',
  990264: '2018-01-30',
  121543: '2018-06-26',
  255129: '2018-09-20'},
 'id': {379724: '110000078451',
  379725: '110000078451',
  414510: '110000078451',
  414509: '110000078451',
  414511: '110000078451',
  507215: '110000078451',
  507213: '110000078451',
  507214: '110000078451',
  507235: '110000078451',
  562139: '110000078451',
  672967: '110000078451',
  672968: '110000078451',
  672969: '110000078451',
  910729: '110000078451',
  990263: '110000078451',
  990265: '110000078451',
  990264: '110000078451',
  121543: '110000078451',
  255129: '110000078451'},
 'limit': {379724: 0,
  379725: 1,
  414510: 1,
  414509: 0,
  414511: 0,
  507215: 0,
  507213: 0,
  507214: 1,
  507235: 0,
  562139: 0,
  672967: 0,
  672968: 0,
  672969: 0,
  910729: 0,
  990263: 0,
  990265: 0,
  990264: 0,
  121543: 0,
  255129: 0})
```

And I need to count the number of times the value in `'limit'` changes to another for each group of `'id'`.

The code I came up with is:

```py
count01 = df.groupby('id')['limit'].rolling(2,min_periods=1)
.apply(lambda x: ((x[0] != x[-1]) & (x[0] == 1)), raw=True)
.groupby('id').sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='count01')

count10 = df.groupby('id')['limit'].rolling(2,min_periods=1)
.apply(lambda x: ((x[0] != x[-1]) & (x[0] == 0)), raw=True)
.groupby('id').sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='count10')

count_total = count01.merge(count10, on='id')
```

Sometimes it provides correct results and sometimes it doesn't. I think that the first `apply` value in a group may be assigned NaN and the result is affected by that but maybe it is not it.

The result should be:

```py
id          | count01 | count10
-------------------------------
110000078451| 2       | 2
```

Thanks!

Edit: I updated my example to be more in line with the real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a column with the transitions inside the same id, and then use pivot_table to count those transitions:

```
df2 = df.shift()
df2['limit'] = df2['limit'].bfill().astype(int)  # force limit to type int in shifted df
df.loc[(df.id==df2.id)&(df.limit!=df2.limit),'transition'] = \
                                   df2.limit.astype(str)+df.limit.astype(str)

resul = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='transition', aggfunc='count',values='date', fill_value=0)
```

giving:

```
transition  01  10
id                
111          2   1
22           0   1
```

You can improve the presentation:

```
resul = resul.rename(columns=lambda x: 'count'+x).rename_axis('', axis=1).reset_index()
```

to finally get:

```
    id  count01  count10
0  111        2        1
1   22        0        1
```

Comment: @gribna I forgot the first line when copying from my tests... Edited.

Comment: I tried it on my real data and it provided the wrong result. For example, this sequence (0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0) for one id resulted in count01 = 1 and count10 = 1

Comment: @gribna: cannot reproduce this problem. I get 2 for both. Can you share some data exhibiting the error?

Comment: I updated the example with real data. When I run your code it gives me
id count0.01 count1.00

0 110000078451 3 3

Comment: @gribna: I could reproduce and fix. I just forgot to ensure that `limit` was an int in the shifted dataframe. Edited.

Comment: Your code works with the example. But when applied to the real data the count is off. I tested it on three groups (imported from dictionary) with short sequences and it worked. Yet it doesn't work with a dataframe loaded from csv. Same column names, same everything and the resulting numbers are off. I don't get it.

Comment: Could you share the csv on an external folder (google, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

in count01 change:

```
(x[0] == 1)) --> (x[0] == 0))
```

and in count10 change:

```
(x[0] == 0)) --> (x[0] == 1))
```

Comment: By your proposed change it would count transitions from 1 to 0 and from 0 to 1 respectively then. But some other mistake in the original code still remains as the results are not always right.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import pandas as pd


def limit_change_counter(limits, _from, _to):
    tmp = list(limits)
    counter = 0
    for idx, limit in enumerate(tmp):
        if idx > 0:
            if tmp[idx - 1] == _from and limit == _to:
                counter += 1
    return counter


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'date': {379724: '2017-01-31',
                                      379725: '2017-01-31',
                                      414510: '2017-02-14',
                                      414509: '2017-02-28',
                                      414511: '2017-02-28',
                                      507215: '2017-04-27',
                                      507213: '2017-04-27',
                                      507214: '2017-04-27',
                                      507235: '2017-04-27',
                                      562139: '2017-04-27',
                                      672967: '2017-07-27',
                                      672968: '2017-07-27',
                                      672969: '2017-07-27',
                                      910729: '2017-12-07',
                                      990263: '2018-01-30',
                                      990265: '2018-01-30',
                                      990264: '2018-01-30',
                                      121543: '2018-06-26',
                                      255129: '2018-09-20'},
                             'id': {379724: '110000078451',
                                    379725: '110000078451',
                                    414510: '110000078451',
                                    414509: '110000078451',
                                    414511: '110000078451',
                                    507215: '110000078451',
                                    507213: '110000078451',
                                    507214: '110000078451',
                                    507235: '110000078451',
                                    562139: '110000078451',
                                    672967: '110000078451',
                                    672968: '110000078451',
                                    672969: '110000078451',
                                    910729: '110000078451',
                                    990263: '110000078451',
                                    990265: '110000078451',
                                    990264: '110000078451',
                                    121543: '110000078451',
                                    255129: '110000078451'},
                             'limit': {379724: 0,
                                       379725: 1,
                                       414510: 1,
                                       414509: 0,
                                       414511: 0,
                                       507215: 0,
                                       507213: 0,
                                       507214: 1,
                                       507235: 0,
                                       562139: 0,
                                       672967: 0,
                                       672968: 0,
                                       672969: 0,
                                       910729: 0,
                                       990263: 0,
                                       990265: 0,
                                       990264: 0,
                                       121543: 0,
                                       255129: 0}})

df.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)
print(df)

df['limit_changes_0_to_1'] = df.groupby(['id'])['limit'].transform(limit_change_counter, 0, 1)
df['limit_changes_1_to_0'] = df.groupby(['id'])['limit'].transform(limit_change_counter, 1, 0)
df.drop_duplicates(subset="id", keep="first", inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Comment: The goal is to count the changes in limit within each id group for each unique value of limit (0 and 1). So there is a change 0->1 and a change 1->0 that have to be counted separately.

Comment: @gribna Got it. Code was changed.

Comment: I copied your code but it always gives me zeroes in the results.

Comment: @gribna Let me do a double check. I will copy the code from stackoverflow and let you know what is the output.

Comment: @gribna Here is the code python code https://pastebin.com/eT7bYPzv and it generates this output https://pastebin.com/a6EVSg0Q . So it seems to work

Comment: I've run the code here with a better example: https://repl.it/repls/StandardExhaustedBrain

Comment: @gribna Got it :-). Just change `df['limit_changes_0_to_1'] = df.groupby(['id'])['limit'].transform(limit_change_counter, '0', '1')` to `df['limit_changes_0_to_1'] = df.groupby(['id'])['limit'].transform(limit_change_counter, 0, 1)` and the other line as well.

Comment: so the call to `transform` uses the numbers 0,1 and NOT the string '0','1'

Comment: @gribna I have updated the code in the answer as well.

Comment: The code provides correct results on a small piece of data with a several 'id' groups but if I copy-paste it to use on the real dataframe it gives the wrong numbers. (Very high counts.) Could it work differently on a csv-imported dataframe?

Comment: @gribna I don't think there is a reason that it will work differently on csv based df.  You can share the csv in order to verify.